# DJANGO: How to allow Users to change password?

Tags: python, django, passwords, django-templates, authentication

So I have Users (from django.contrib.auth.models import User) and UserProfiles. in my UserProfile view there is an edit link. This edit link allows a User to change their User settings. In the password section of the form I see help text that says:

```
"Use '[algo]$[salt]$[hexdigest]' or use the change password form."
```

The "change password form" is actually a link to http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/1/user_edit/password/, when I click the link I get an error message saying:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /user/1/user_edit/password/

Could not import testdb.views.django.contrib.auth.views. Error was: No module named django.contrib.auth.views
```

I've been following the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

What am I doing wrong? I hear that this should use djangos templates, do I need to copy those over to my apps template folder? if so, where are they?

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('testdb.views',
url(r'^$', 'index'),
url(r'^^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'user_detail'),
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/user_edit/$', 'user_edit'),
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/user_edit/password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name': 'password_change_form'}),
)
```

Comment: Can you post the full urls.py? Have you imported django.contrib.auth.views.password_change?

Comment: i have from django.contrib.auth.views import * in my VIEWS.py and Ive updated my URLS.py

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong URL pattern defined: Django tries to find `testdb.views.django.contrib.auth.views` as you define the password_change view inside `patterns('testdb.views',`.

Add a second pattern:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
  url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/user_edit/password/$', 'password_change')
)
```

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: No need for that import if you're referencing the view as a string.

Comment: it sorta works, i get an error saying password_change() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'

Comment: This is due to the "(?P<user_id>\d+)" bit of your pattern; rename it to match the password_change() signature... i.e. remove it.

Answer (score 0):

cfedermann has a solution to your issue, but I'm confused as to why you've defined the password_change URL in the first place. This functionality is built-in to the admin, and - like all the other admin pages - the URL is defined already by the admin code itself.

Comment: defined the url as in this "url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/user_edit/password/$', 'password_change')"? I did so because my password field in my edit user/userprofile form uses that url.

Comment: This is for your own view, outside of the admin? In which case I think the problem is that your URLconf is overriding the one defined in contrib.auth, so the admin is trying to link to yours instead of the built-in one. Try changing the name of your own one.

Comment: yes this is outside of the admin. so a User of this system can change their own password. Sorry im new to django/python how do you change the name? What I'm really trying to do is have a form that allows the user to change their password. is there some easier/correct way of doing this? should I create a custom form for submitting a new password instead? this is still not working for me.

Comment: Well, you could also just activate the admin backend and allow users to change their passwords there...